# How to edit a data type (Map) in Firestore from Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this information "Tarifas" which is a map and I am trying to edit it in my Flutter application

but i haven't found a correct way to do it:

this is my data in Firestore

[image]

and this is the code that I have tried

```
Firestore.instance
          .collection("parqueaderos")
          .document(widget.idparking)
          .updateData({
            "tarifas['Carros']" : tCarros,
            "tarifas['Motos']" : tMotos,
            "tarifas['Bicicletas']" : tBicicletas,
          });
```

I'm looking for an idea how to edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```dart
Firestore.instance
          .collection("parqueaderos")
          .document(widget.idparking)
          .updateData({
            "tarifas.Carros" : tCarros,
            "tarifas.Motos" : tMotos,
            "tarifas.Bicicletas" : tBicicletas,
          });
```

Comment: oh so simple man, it didn't occur to me!
Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem man. If this answer worked, please mark it as the answer to help others with the same question